# OSX用にビルドしたアプリが開けない。

Tags: macos, unity2d

Unityプロジェクトで作成したOSX用アプリケーションをWeb配信しました。
Webからダウンロードすると「アプリケーション"アプリ名"を開けません。」と表示されます。
セキュリティ設定で「App Storeと確認済みの開発元からのアプリケーションを許可」に変更しています。
ビルドで出力されたアプリは開けるのですが、Webからダウンロードしてくると開けなくなります。

Unity上でセキュリティの修正は何処で行えばよいのでしょうか。

環境
Unity2018.3.13f1
Mac OS Catalina
バージョン　10.15.4

Answer (score 1):

決め手に欠けますが、以下が原因になりえます。

### 実行権限がついていない場合

`アプリ名.app/Contents/MacOS/*` に実行権限 `+x` がついているか確認してみてください。
実行権限がついていない場合にこのエラーが出ることがあります。

参考: https://superuser.com/q/898124/680903

### うまく解凍できていない場合

Catalina の最初の方のバージョンでは、デフォルトの解凍ソフトにバグがあります。他の解凍ソフトで解凍した場合も同じエラーが出るか確かめてみてください。

### Nortalization できていない場合

これが原因とするとエラーメッセージが違うはずなのですが、Catalina からチェックが厳しくなった [nortalization](https://developer.apple.com/jp/news/?id=10032019a) (公証) に引っかかっている可能性も念の為書いておきます。回避するにはアプリを nortalize してください。